# unable to go function implementation vim

Tags: c++, vim, cmake, ctags

I am using vim to wite a software. Here i am using ctags to go to functin definition and declaration. What my problem is when i type :`ctrl+]` it jumps to function declaration part in obj_rec.h file but it don't goes to obj_rec.cpp part from d main.cpp file. I also created tag file by using cmd, `ctags -R --exclude=.git .`  and `ctags -R` and `ctags -R -f`
but it is also not working. Here is how the files looks:
test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H


class test
{
public:
  test();
};
testFunc();
#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
test::test()
{
  std::cout<<"test called"<<std::endl;    
}
testFunc() { std::cout<<"test func"<<std::endl;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
int main() 
{
    test obj;
    test(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Here when i put my cursor in the test class or test function in the main.cpp file it jumps to test.h file not in test.cpp. What should i do to jump to test.cpp where its implementation is present using ctags?

Here is how my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

```
project(ai_vision)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} /usr/include/CL/)
set(src main.cpp obj_rec.cpp mean_shift.cpp use_opencl.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${src})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL.so)
```

I'm using ubuntu 18.04, vim version 8.0.

Comment: The `test` in your main file is the class itself (defined in the test.h), not the constructor (defined in test.cpp). That behavior is expected; clicking on `test` in your main file **should** take you to test.h.

Comment: shouldn't it be also going to the definition of that constructor? what if i want to go to testFunc() definition which is present in test.cpp?

Comment: Not necessarily, `test` by itself is just a type, which should take you to the definition of the type (in the header). Your edits don't make much sense, particularly the `test()` in the main file. Did you intend to explicitly call a constructor here?

Answer (score 0):

To go to the function definition where the function is implemented you have to use tags feature of ctags. Instead of going to function definition. For this you have to use cmd:

> tag funcName

as also described in [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags) documentation.
After this in your case just type: tag testFunc than it will go to test.cpp file test functin.